# Random missing product name in random orders

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, order-items

On rare and random occasions (once or twice a month) our client receives an order with **one missing product name** in the items list (see attached screenshot) - however the product name exists and is shown correctly on other orders.

[image: Missing product name in order]

- It is never the same product
- It is never the same client
- It is never the same day, month nor day
- It is never the same quantity ordered
- The product can contain special characters (as almost every item)

However it seems to happen when there are multiple products ordered.

The problem is not that the quote from Magento would lacking the product name, but there is a third party service hooked up which handles the quotes. And an order with one item lacking its product name is breaking their system (stops adding the following items therefor the quote shows 2 items for a value of ex. 17€ instead of 7 items for 68€).

The issue is not reproducible on our side (we tried multiple times).

Did someone encounter this kind of behaviour from Magento?

Do you need more information, so please don't hesitate to add a comment, thank you all in advance!

**Magento version: 1.9.2.1**

Edit:

*Here is a screenshot of the SQL result asked for in the comments*
[image: SQL query "select name from sales_flat_quote_item where quote_id IN (select entity_id from sales_flat_quote where reserved_order_id = 100008362)"]

So what could this mean?

Comment: Does the product name appear on the quote item, before it is purchased? It could be lost when the quote items are converted into order items. Also, check the product names for special characters, accents, etc.

Comment: @ProcessEight almost all products have special characters and accents (French shop). Also the product name appears correctly on the quote item (at least on my tryouts).

Comment: @Marc-AndréAppel please check the database to see if the products always have the name in quotes. You can check on an real order: select name from sales_flat_quote_item where quote_id IN (select quote_id from sales_flat_quote where reserved_order_id = "ORDER_NUMBER_HERE")

Comment: @FraH you mean "select entity_id from sales_flat_quote ..."? If so, the product name in question is here NULL.

Comment: can you check the data from the `sales_flat_quote_Item` table ? Is the `name` column is empty for those orders ?

Comment: @Chester I edited my question to add the SQL result you asked for, thank you for your efforts end time!

Comment: @FraH I edited my question to add the SQL result from your suggestion, thank you for your efforts and time!

Comment: @Marc-AndréAppel , it could mean a lot of things. Do you have some customization for products ? maybe some observers ? I would check all of the custom or from paid module observers related to quotes . Also have you checked the logs ? You have the order creation date , so you should able to used that to extract some info from the logs.

Comment: @Chester I followed your suggestion concerning all the logs, but a dead end. Is there a easy and fast way to know (or see from the code) which of those tens of installed modules interferes with orders?

Comment: from the `sales_flat_quote_item` is it just the name null ? do you have the right qty, sku etc ? Is there a order_id ?

Comment: so you didn't find these observers in your project ?: `sales_order_place_before`
`sales_order_place_after`, `checkout_submit_all_after`  . BTW is about order placed from frontend or adminpanel ? There must be a pattern to identify all of these orders :)

Comment: @Chester Everything seems alright, as you can see here: https://imgur.com/a/bs9t1SX. 
The orders are always placed on the frontend (from always different clients).

Comment: @Chester and for those observers, after searching the code base and excluding core components I might have 2 modules I'll have to analyse.